# Unable to rename a file, delete, create a new folder, cut, paste in a volume neither by terminal nor by GUI

Tags: command-line, gui

```
shubbh@Tuxedo:/media/shubbh/New Volume$ sudo rm resume.pdf abc.pdf
rm: cannot remove 'resume.pdf': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove 'abc.pdf': No such file or directory
shubbh@Tuxedo:/media/shubbh/New Volume$ sudo mv resume.pdf Songs
mv: cannot move 'resume.pdf' to 'Songs/resume.pdf': Read-only file system
shubbh@Tuxedo:/media/shubbh/New Volume$ sudo mkdir a
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘a’: Read-only file system
```

Comment: "Read-only" means you can only read from, not write to, delete or move from. You need to change the permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
exec sudo -i
fdisk -l
```

fdisk report as they are called partitions mounted in the system.

Suppose /media/shubbh/New Volume is /dev/sdc1

Continue running

```
umount /media/shubbh/New\ Volume
fsck -y /dev/sdc1
mkdir /media/shubbh/New\ Volume
chmod -Rf 777 /media/shubbh/New\ Volume
mount /dev/sdc1 /media/shubbh/New\ Volume
exit
```

And try to rename a file, delete, create a new folder, cut, paste in a volume neither by terminal

Comment: **shubbh@Tuxedo:/media/shubbh/New Volume$** umount /media/shubbh/New\ Volume
Error unmounting block device 8:6: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Error.DeviceBusy: Error unmounting /dev/sda6: Command-line `umount  "/media/shubbh/New Volume"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: umount: /media/shubbh/New Volume: target is busy
        (In some cases useful info about processes that
         use the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1).)

@kyodake Still an error while running the given command

Comment: **shubbh@Tuxedo:~$** sudo umount /dev/sda6
 umount: /media/shubbh/New Volume: target is busy
        (In some cases useful info about processes that
         use the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1).)